# Add product to cart on a non shop page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, qweb, odoo-12

We are using the software of Odoo 12 for enterprises.

We want to duplicate the behaviour of the add to cart button on the product pages. 
So we want to add a button on a different page and when you click the button you add a product to your cart and get redirected to your cart. 
The product is hardcoded to that button.

This is the form used on the product page template:

```
       <form t-if="product._is_add_to_cart_possible()" action="/shop/cart/update" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
          <div class="js_product js_main_product">
            <t t-placeholder="select">
              <input type="hidden" class="product_id" name="product_id" t-att-value="product_variant.id"/>
              <input type="hidden" class="product_template_id" name="product_template_id" t-att-value="product.id"/>
              <t t-if="first_possible_combination" t-call="sale.variants">
                <t t-set="ul_class" t-value="'flex-column'"/>
                <t t-set="parent_combination" t-value="None"/>
              </t>
              <t t-else="">
                <ul class="d-none js_add_cart_variants" t-att-data-attribute_exclusions="{'exclusions: []'}"/>
              </t>
            </t>
            <t t-call="website_sale.product_price"/>
            <p t-if="True" class="css_not_available_msg alert alert-warning">This combination does not exist.</p>
            <a role="button" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
          </div>
        </form>
```

The info of our product: `product.id = 135` and `product_template.id = 83`.

I've found that the javascript responsible for the adding to the cart is called using: `/web/content/.../.../web.assets_frontend.js`. This is a very large file but you can check an example here: [file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3e23e9837a985edebff69caee9cd82df20190903154428/cf9caa).

Which qweb/form/js/... should I add on my custom page to add a product to my cart?

Thanks for any help, I've been stuck on this for a long time!

**Edit**: 
As @Philippe Pageau pointed out I can use some code to get the correct product already. I've tried implementing it with the form using this code (the simplest version of the form I can think of):

```
      <t t-set="products" t-value="request.env['product.product'].search([['id', '=', 135]])"/>
        <t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
          <form action="/shop/cart/update" method="POST">
             <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
             <input type="hidden" class="product_id" name="product_id" value="135"/>
             <input type="hidden" class="product_template_id" name="product_template_id" value="83"/>
             <a role="button" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
          </form>
      </t>
```

But this does nothing, what am I missing?

**Edit2**:

Thanks to @Adan Cortes we are further now but there is still 1 problem.

Now when the user clicks on a button the products gets added to the cart with a specific quantity.

This is my code now:

```
<t t-set="products" t-value="request.env['product.product'].search([['id', '=', 135]])"/>
      <t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
        <div id="product_detail" class="oe_website_sale">
          <form action="/shop/cart/update" method="POST">
              <h4 t-esc="product.name"/>
              <h6 t-esc="product.price"/>
              <input class="form-control" data-min="1" name="add_qty" value="1"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
              <input type="hidden" class="product_id" name="product_id" value="135"/>
              <a role="button" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </t>
```

But these are my final problems:

- This code doesn't show the product price. `<h6 t-esc="product.price"/>` displays `0.00`. So how can I display the price?
- Finally is it possible to add multiple products at once using only 1 button and form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works:

```
<div id="product_detail" class="oe_website_sale">
    <form action="/shop/cart/update" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="product_id" name="product_id" value="135"/>
        <a role="button" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

But beware that using the database id makes your module unusable elsewhere. You better use xmlids.

The relevant JavaScript you were missing is at:

`<path_to_v12>/addons/website_sale/static/src/js/website_sale.js`

```
135 sAnimations.registry.WebsiteSale = sAnimations.Class.extend(ProductConfiguratorMixin, {
136     selector: '.oe_website_sale',
137     read_events: {
138         'change form .js_product:first input[name="add_qty"]': '_onChangeAddQuantity',
139         'mouseup .js_publish': '_onMouseupPublish',
140         'touchend .js_publish': '_onMouseupPublish',
141         'change .oe_cart input.js_quantity[data-product-id]': '_onChangeCartQuantity',
142         'click .oe_cart a.js_add_suggested_products': '_onClickSuggestedProduct',
143         'click a.js_add_cart_json': '_onClickAddCartJSON',
144         'click .a-submit': '_onClickSubmit',
145         'change form.js_attributes input, form.js_attributes select': '_onChangeAttribute',
146         'mouseup form.js_add_cart_json label': '_onMouseupAddCartLabel',
147         'touchend form.js_add_cart_json label': '_onMouseupAddCartLabel',
148         'click .show_coupon': '_onClickShowCoupon',
149         'submit .o_website_sale_search': '_onSubmitSaleSearch',
150         'change select[name="country_id"]': '_onChangeCountry',
151         'change #shipping_use_same': '_onChangeShippingUseSame',
152         'click .toggle_summary': '_onToggleSummary',
153         'click input.js_product_change': 'onChangeVariant',
154         'change .js_main_product [data-attribute_exclusions]': 'onChangeVariant',
155     },
```

and `<path_to_v12>/addons/website_sale/static/src/js/website_sale_tracking.js`

```
  5 sAnimations.registry.websiteSaleTracking = sAnimations.Class.extend({
  6     selector: '.oe_website_sale',
  7     read_events: {
  8         'click form[action="/shop/cart/update"] a.a-submit': '_onAddProductIntoCart',
  9         'click a[href="/shop/checkout"]': '_onCheckoutStart',
 10         'click div.oe_cart a[href^="/web?redirect"][href$="/shop/checkout"]': '_onCustomerSignin',
 11         'click form[action="/shop/confirm_order"] a.a-submit': '_onOrder',
 12         'click form[target="_self"] button[type=submit]': '_onOrderPayment',
 13     },
```

**Edited to add**

The form data is processed and dispatched by the following controller:

`<path_to_v12>/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py`

```
414     @http.route(['/shop/cart/update'], type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True, csrf=False)
415     def cart_update(self, product_id, add_qty=1, set_qty=0, **kw):
416         """This route is called when adding a product to cart (no options)."""
418         sale_order = request.website.sale_get_order(force_create=True)
419         if sale_order.state != 'draft':
420             request.session['sale_order_id'] = None
421             sale_order = request.website.sale_get_order(force_create=True)
422 
423         product_custom_attribute_values = None
424         if kw.get('product_custom_attribute_values'):
425             product_custom_attribute_values = json.loads(kw.get('product_custom_attribute_values'))
426 
427         no_variant_attribute_values = None
428         if kw.get('no_variant_attribute_values'):
429             no_variant_attribute_values = json.loads(kw.get('no_variant_attribute_values'))
430 
431         sale_order._cart_update(
432             product_id=int(product_id),
433             add_qty=add_qty,
434             set_qty=set_qty,
435             product_custom_attribute_values=product_custom_attribute_values,
436             no_variant_attribute_values=no_variant_attribute_values
437         )
438         return request.redirect("/shop/cart")
```

Comment: This works great already! But I've got some additional variables I would like to add: 1. can I add a specific qty? 2. Can I add multiple games at once using the same form? 3. Can I add to cart but not redirect to the cart page? I will definitely do research myself but if you know these answers on the top of your head it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: 1. Yes, you can; 2 and 3. You have to override the controller.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is you need to request the product since it not only asks for the product's, but the template's as well.

I fetch all my products for my purchase order page.
As such, here's how I create my product variable.

```
<t t-set="products" t-value="request.env['product.product'].search([])/>
<t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
<!-- your code here -->
</t>
```

To search for a specific product

```
.search(['id', '=', yourId])
```

Note that it'll return you an array even with a specified id

Comment: It's my first time helping, so don't hesitate to ask more or to tell me what I didn't understand in the question.