# How to add form values to cart in odoo 12

Tags: e-commerce, cart, shopping-cart, odoo-12

I have a custom selection box and 2 textboxes. The selection box has a product name(Test-Product) loaded in it from product.template while the 2 textboxes are for quantity and price. The quantity has a default hidden value of 1. What I want to do is to add the selection box, quantity and price to cart.

​I tried to get some idea from the link below but when click add to cart button nothing happens.
[Add product to cart on a non shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254307/add-product-to-cart-on-a-non-shop-page)

My screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/ikyZ5uPfsj1y.png